# What are the differences between laryngitis, chronic obstructive pulmonary disease (COPD), & whooping cough?

Tags: copd, laryngitis

What are the differences between laryngitis, chronic obstructive pulmonary disease (COPD), & whooping cough?

Do cough drops and cough syrups help in all of these different forms of coughs?